# I want to decode html entity into text and then perform string.contain operation

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

my textbox data

```
txtdata = "java&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116 is good."
```

i want to decode it like "javascript is good."
i have used `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` and `htmlutility.htmldecode` but its not working.

when i used

```
String check = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(txtdata);
```

or

```
HtmlUtility.HtmlDecode(txtdata);
```

and then try to use

```
 if  (check.Contains("javascript") == true)
```

it shows `false`
i tried debugging and it shows the same text in check string as original "**java&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116 is good.**"

what can i do?
thank you.

Comment: How are you encoding it on the client side? I suggest going for URI.encodeUriComponent and then use URI.UnescapeDataString() function of C# in the backend. This is better approach as you will be sending data over URI's in terms of HTTP requests

Comment: i knw,Actually i am doing a project on xss prevention for that i want this.thank you.

Comment: You want to prevent XSS, but the way you are trying to achieve is questionable. If i just don't write the word `javascript`, it will still happen. What you can do is to follow the approach i suggested then use an Anti-XSS library. It doesn't really make a difference how you encode it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML string is not well encoded, you have missed semicolons.
It should be:

```
txtdata = "java&#115;&#99;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#116; is good.";
```

With correctly encoded string both `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` and `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` will return `javascript is good.`